# Changing the format of a table from multiple rows to multiple columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe

so for example this is how my current dataframe/table looks:

| # | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 10% |
| a | 2 | 11.1% |
| a | 3 | 8% |
| b | 1 | 7% |
| b | 2 | 13.1% |
| b | 3 | 6% |

and I'm trying to change it to:

| # | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 10% | 2 | 11.1% | 3 | 8% |
| b | 1 | 7% | 2 | 13.1% | 3 | 6% |

In other words rather than multiple rows where data is getting repeated, looking for a more compact format where everything regarding the same variable is in the same row.

Comment: the 2nd row in expected result must contain `1` for `C1` column

Answer (score 1):

With [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to arrange values horizontally:

```
df = df.groupby('#').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.hstack(x.values[:, 1:])))\
    .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis('C' + (x.columns + 1).astype(str), axis=1))\
    .reset_index()
```

---

```
   #  C1   C2  C3     C4  C5  C6
0  a   1  10%   2  11.1%   3  8%
1  b   1   7%   2  13.1%   3  6%
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```py
result = (
    df.assign(cols=df.groupby("#").cumcount().add(1))
    .pivot(index="#", columns="cols").sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
    .set_axis([f"C{n}" for n in range(1, 7)], axis=1).reset_index()
)
```

Result:

```
   #  C1   C2  C3     C4  C5  C6
0  a   1  10%   2  11.1%   3  8%
1  b   1   7%   2  13.1%   3  6%
```

I haven't used `C1` here to ceate the `cols` column since I'm assuming the actual items  are different. If that's not the case, then you could do:

```py
result = (
    df.assign(cols=df["C1"])
    .pivot(index="#", columns="cols").sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
    .set_axis([f"C{n}" for n in range(1, 7)], axis=1).reset_index()
)
```